# Проблема с получением значения в PHP

Tags: php

Проблема заключается в том, что если допустим загрузить страницу ниже, то `$_GET['message']` будет почему-то пустым

> `index.php?message=%u041D%u043E%u0447%u044C%2C%20%u0443%u043B%u0438%u0446%u0430%2C%20%u0444%u043E%u043D%u0430%u0440%u044C%2C%20%u0430%u043F%u0442%u0435%u043A%u0430%2C%0A%u0411%u0435%u0441%u0441%u043C%u044B%u0441%u043B%u0435%u043D%u043D%u044B%u0439%20%u0438%20%u0442%u0443%u0441%u043A%u043B%u044B%u0439%20%u0441%u0432%u0435%u0442.%0A%u0416%u0438%u0432%u0438%20%u0435%u0449%u0435%20%u0445%u043E%u0442%u044C%20%u0447%u0435%u0442%u0432%u0435%u0440%u0442%u044C%20%u0432%u0435%u043A%u0430%20-%0A%u0412%u0441%u0435%20%u0431%u0443%u0434%u0435%u0442%20%u0442%u0430%u043A.%20%u0418%u0441%u0445%u043E%u0434%u0430%20%u043D%u0435%u0442.%0A%0A%u0423%u043C%u0440%u0435%u0448%u044C%20-%20%u043D%u0430%u0447%u043D%u0435%u0448%u044C%20%u043E%u043F%u044F%u0442%u044C%20%u0441%u043D%u0430%u0447%u0430%u043B%u0430%0A%u0418%20%u043F%u043E%u0432%u0442%u043E%u0440%u0438%u0442%u0441%u044F%20%u0432%u0441%u0435%2C%20%u043A%u0430%u043A%20%u0432%u0441%u0442%u0430%u0440%u044C%3A%0A%u041D%u043E%u0447%u044C%2C%20%u043B%u0435%u0434%u044F%u043D%u0430%u044F%20%u0440%u044F%u0431%u044C%20%u043A%u0430%u043D%u0430%u043B%u0430%2C%0A%u0410%u043F%u0442%u0435%u043A%u0430%2C%20%u0443%u043B%u0438%u0446%u0430%2C%20%u0444%u043E%u043D%u0430%u0440%u044C.`

В то время, как если загрузить

> index.php?message=%u041D%u043E%u0447%u044C%2C%20

То в $_GET['message'] будет информация %u041D%u043E%u0447%u044C%2C%20. В чём проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Русский текст переводится в URL код для фикса используй http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php  
Но в php Гет и Пост уже переведены в понятный русский.

Comment: Проблема в том, что оно вообще ничего не содержит

Comment: Проблема в том что вы не понимаете о чем  говорит @activist
Посмотрите в error лог апача/nginx и всё станет понятно.

зы: На моём php/apache этот запрос обрабатывает корректно.

Answer (score 1):

А что в QUERY_STRING ? 
По стандартам SGML длина URL не должна превышать 1024 символа.